# Undefined offset: 0 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My framework is Laravel 5.2, There is no record in the database.
But in this Site, it has error.

Error is:

```
ErrorException in Collection.php line 1187:
Undefined offset: 0
```

Controller is:

```
public function index()
{
    $comment = ProviderComment::GetComments($ID);

    return $comment;
}
```

Model is:

```
public function scopeGetComments($query, $vendorID)
{
    $join = $query
        -> join('couples', 'couples.id', '=', 'provider_comment.couple_id')
        -> where('provider_comment.vendor_id', '=', $vendorID)
        -> get();
    return $join;
}
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Pls do dd($$join) & show the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $comment = ProviderComment::getComments($ID)->get();
    return $comment; }
```

Model:

```
public function scopeGetComments($query, $vendorID)
{
    return $query
        ->join('couples', 'couples.id', '=', 'provider_comment.couple_id')
        ->where('provider_comment.vendor_id', '=', $vendorID);
}
```

Don't use `get()` directly on scopes.

> More about [scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Thank you so mush for your help, I realized my problem.